# displaying data depending on the data from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I am just a beginner in mysql and I want to know on how will I display all the books that a certain username only borrow, yet the admin can still delete the book data after the book was returned. It's like this: all the students are only limited in borrowing and returning the book and all the faculties can do the delete, update and insert books; and it works fine. My problem is when I student as a user( for example is Joann), I cannot display all the books she borrowed.

I hope you can help me in this.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more by providing sample tables and attempts you've made, and your desired result? Please provide sample tables in text, cause other readers can't see the image.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Admins probably shouldn't be deleting book data